# Comparing PHP arrays with integers, what is the real behavior

Tags: php, arrays

Today I faced a weird behavior on PHP (v: 7.1) arrays.

```
$emptyArray = [];

echo empty($emptyArray);

echo count($emptyArray);

echo (($emptyArray > 0));
```

The first two echos results is known (empty : true , count: 0), but the last one which confused me returned **true**!

Why PHP considered an empty array is larger than zero ?!

Comment: Not sure why you would do the last one - any particular reason?

Comment: Everything is described in http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Strange behavior ;-) Maybe something here could help you : [http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why PHP considered an empty array is larger than zero ?!

It is written in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types): when it is compared with an object of a different type, the array is always greater.

Comment: php __can__ compare arrays with whatever, and as written in link you provided - `array is always greater`.

Comment: So, [`array() > 'Brray'`](https://3v4l.org/WvLuR) should be `false`, yes?

Comment: @u_mulder I corrected the answer. Thank you for pointing that out; it seems I missed this part of the page until today.

Comment: @deceze only for very large values of `'Brray'` ;-) I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to be found in the rules for [comparisons between different types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types):

```
Operand 1    Operand 2    Result
...          ...          ...
array        anything     array is always greater
```